# How to define a map in a YAML file for simple POJO?

Tags: java, yaml, pojo, snakeyaml

I am using [SnakeYAML](https://bitbucket.org/snakeyaml/snakeyaml) to parse certain configuration/property values to a Configuration object (defined below).

My YAML file looks like this:

```
# Thread
batchLimit: 1000
threadCountLimit: 2

# Some more config
key: value

# Map
keyMapping: <What goes here?>
```

My Configuration class looks like this:

```
public class Configuration{
  int batchlimit;
  int threadCountLimit;
  ...
  Map<String,String> keyMapping;
}
```

How do I define the `keyMapping` in the YAML file so it can be parsed directly by SnakeYAML?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Here is how it can look like:

```
#MAP
keyMapping: 
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
```

Generally YAML format has natural support of key-value pairs. 
Take a look on the following tutorial (just for example): https://github.com/Animosity/CraftIRC/wiki/Complete-idiot's-introduction-to-yaml

Or just google "yaml map" for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't even think of trying this. Was getting weird results like using '?' for keys and ':' for values. You saved so much of my time

Comment: I also googled yml map and ended up here.
Just a future idea type in a link instead, or stop typing.....While you are ahead.
It was a really nice answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yaml file "AppParams.yml" with key-value pairs:

```
someConfig:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
```

POJO:

```
public class ApplicationParameters {
    private Map<String, String> someConfig;

    public ApplicationParameters() {
    }

    public Map<String, String> getSomeConfig() {
        return someConfig;
    }

    public void setSomeConfig(Map<String, String> someConfig) {
        this.someConfig = someConfig;
    }
}
```

Reader:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
File paramFile = new File("AppParams.yml");
ApplicationParameters applicationParameters = mapper.readValue(paramFile, ApplicationParameters.class);

Map<String, String> someConfig = applicationParameters.getSomeConfig();

String key1Value = someConfig.get("key1");    //returns "value1"
```

The example above uses these dependencies in POM.xml:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```