# Read config from application.yml to Map of List of POJO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have this **application.yml** file

```
messages:
  first-journey-messages:
    - key: fullName-required
      value: This field is required.
    - key: fullName-validation
      value: Please enter a valid full name.
    - key: technical-error
      value: Unfortunately we are having technical issues, please try again later.
  second-journey-messages:
    - key: technical-error
      value: "<p class='heading-bold'>Sorry, something went wrong </p><p>We encountered a technical error. Please try again. If you continue to experience difficulties, please call us on 0123456 and an agent will be happy to assist you.</p>"
    - key: download-technical-error
      value: "<p class='heading-bold'>Sorry, something went wrong </p><p>Unable to download document at this moment. Please try again later.</p>"
  third-journey-messages:
    - key: home-url
      value: /app/home
    - key: services-url
      value: /app/services
```

I want to read above configuration in below `Map` object using `@Value` annotation.

```
@Value("${messages}")
private Map<String, List<MessageEntry>> messagesMap = new HashMap<>();
```

POJO: **`MessageEntry`**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MessageEntry implements Serializable {
    private String key;
    private String value;
}
```

When I am trying to read the config, I am getting `null`.

```
messagesMap.get("second-journey-messages")
```

Can someone help me to identify, what am I doing incorrectly?
Or, how can I read the above config as object of type `Map<String, List<MessageEntry>>`?

Note: I am using *spring boot* with *lombok*

Answer (score 0):

I think this answear could help You [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328749/how-to-define-a-map-in-a-yaml-file-for-simple-pojo). Try to change key, value notation in your yml file.